WFP Closing starting window and opening new ones
I need to do something like that:

App starts first window is displayed with some options.
User picks and option on StartWindow.
Depending on that option Windows2 is displayed. User picks some options on Window2.
Depending on options on StartWindow and using some data from Window2, Main window is displayed possibly many times with different data.

Here is my test project, but after closing StartWindow, program flows goes to Windows2 and MainWindow but doesn't display them.
I know its a bit strange, but I'm migrating this from older technology (not .net) and it "must be exactly like before". Only one window displayed at a time.
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            //show start window Always
            new StartWindow().ShowDialog();

            //show this depending on StartWindow option chosen 
            new Window2().ShowDialog();

            //show always (can be many times) depending on options chosen in StartWindow
            new MainWindow().ShowDialog();
        }
    }

Thanks.

Why not rather change the contents of a window rather than trying to show things in dialogs?

ShowDialog is not appropriate here. Move your new Window2().Etc... code into a view-model command-handler for StartWindow.

By default ShutdownMode for the application is set to OnMainWindowClose, so when you closes the first window that appears (StartWindow) the application initializes shutdown and closes.
To fix the issue change the this.MainWindow before you close it. Or you can change ShutdownMode to OnLastWindowClose. In both cases you have to show next window before you close the last window.
So you have to refactor your code. ShowDialog() is not your friend here, use Show() instead and open Window2 from the StartWindow's code.
